# Как сравнить записи в соседних строках и вывести только нужные по условию в pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

В БД posgres есть столбец с датами отсортированными в порядке возрастания. Мне нужно вывести только те даты, между которыми прошло более 10 мин (выделены на скрине в рамку). Можно через sql запрос или в pandas.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншот вставьте в сам вопрос, а на внешний сервис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть специальая оконная функция на этот случай. `LAG` - она возвращает значение предыдущей строки в отсортированном наборе данных

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT create_at, LAG(create_at)OVER(ORDER BY create_at)create_at_lag
  FROM table
)T
--вот тут уже сравнивайте create_at и create_at_lag
```